# BeautifulSoup returns excessive content for <meta> tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Basically I'm trying to get all meta tags from a site with bs4.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://grab.careers/").read()
response_decode = response.decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response_decode,"html.parser")
metatags = soup.find_all('meta')
file = open('text.out','w')
for x in metatags:
    file.write(str(x))
file.close()
```

I expect only meta tags to be returned from the above code. However, the soup returns both meta, links and scripts content as you can see from this snippet:

```
<meta content="Grab Careers | Working For A Better Southeast Asia" name="twitter:title" />
<meta content="Working For A Better Southeast Asia on Grab Careers�" name="twitter:description" />
<link href="https://grab.careers/" rel="canonical">
<script
    type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"WebSite","url":"https://grab.careers/","name":"Grab Careers","potentialAction":{"@type":"SearchAction","target":"https://grab.careers/search/{search_term_string}","query-input":"required name=search_term_string"}}</script>
```

I could not find any resources addressing this problem. How can I fix this so only meta tags are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I cannot exactly figure out why this happens, but it can be resolved if you use `lxml` instead of `html.parser`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response_decode,"lxml")
```

`lxml` packages needs to be installed, e.g. with:
`pip install lxml`

Comment: This works wonderful thanks a lot. I just knew that some closing tags in the response end with ">" instead of "/>" which screw up the html parser. Lxml parser has no problems though.

Answer (score 1):

`find_all` method gives a tag along with all its children.

I think this is happening due to missing closing `/` for empty HTML tags.
The `meta` tags which are closed properly like `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` (note `/` at the end) are parsed as one single tag.

Whereas a meta tag like `<meta content="max-snippet:-1,max-image-preview:standard,max-video-preview:-1" name="robots">` is not parsed as closed tag (due to missing `/`) and thus includes all the tags until a closing `</meta>` is encountered. These children tags actually include the link and script tags that you are seeing.